# How do I trigger the wildcard route when the url parameter is bad?

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-router-params

In Angular 6 I'm using an observable to manage fetching a detail record based on the URL parameter like so:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.hero$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
    switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
      const id = parseInt(params.get('id'), 10);
      if (!id) {
        throw new Error('Hero id invalid.');
      }
      return this.service.getHeroById(id);
    }),
    catchError(err => {
      this.router.navigate(['/pageNotFound'], {skipLocationChange: true});
      return throwError(err);
    }),
  );
}
```

In the catchError pipe I'm just navigating to a URL that doesn't exist which causes the wildcard route to trigger and display my PageNotFoundComponent. That seems really convoluted, but I don't understand how else to cause the router to display that component. Is there a better way?

This is a demo of my setup:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-not-found?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhero%2Fhero-detail.component.ts

Comment: Maybe you could leverage `canActivate` on the route? If that returns false and no other route matches, it should go to your wildcard route

Comment: could you make your stackblitz to run the application not test ?  btw your page is not registred in the router so actually it give us few information

Comment: Futhermore I nearly agree with @Vlad274  except that for me this is the purpose of the **resolver** to resolve data, and if the data can't be resolve it should redirect to the PageNotFoundComponent

Comment: maybe instead of using the wildcard to route to a component, use the wildcard to redirect to another route? something like {path: '**',redirectTo: '404'}

Comment: For me the /pageNotFound route should really exist in the router. Normally you try to use wildcard route to redirect the user to a friendly page. The home page for exemple or a list of data based on the nearest route

Comment: I updated the stackblitz to run the app instead of the tests.

Comment: @Vlad274 Not sure how that would work, got an example of that I can check out? This is what I found, but not sure why this is better. https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-resolve-guard-example